# not install composer require google/cloud-firestore

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

problem

```
composer require google/cloud-firestore
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_grpc.dll' (tried: ext\php_grpc.dll (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado), ext\php_php_grpc.dll.dll (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_grpc.dll' (tried: ext\php_grpc.dll (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado), ext\php_php_grpc.dll.dll (N├úo foi poss├¡vel encontrar o m├│dulo especificado)) in Unknown on line 0
Using version ^0.1.0 for google/cloud-firestore
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update google/cloud-firestore
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires google/cloud-firestore ^0.1.0, found google/cloud-firestore[v0.1.0, v0.1.1] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.    

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require google/cloud-firestore:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require google/cloud-firestore:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install and enable the [gRPC extension](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc) for PHP, which you will need to use the client library.

##### Installing the gRPC extension

```
sudo pecl install grpc
```

This compiles and installs the gRPC PHP extension into the standard PHP extension directory.

Note : Windows users can download the pre-compiled gRPC directly from the [PECL website](https://pecl.php.net/package/grpc).

##### Enable the gRPC extension in `php.ini`

```
extension=grpc.so
```

WIndows? `extension=php_grpc.dll`.